# JXL - How to wrap text (without space) from excel cell

Tags: java, excel, word-wrap, jxl

I created excel using jxl library. I have some text which I want to put in excel cell. I want that cell to have wrap the text. I am able to achieve this by getting help from various resources available out there. But if the text doesn't have space then text wrap not working.

But this works, when I created excel sheet in google sheets online. How can I do this by using jxl api.

Please refer following code taken from here [How to wrap text in Excel Cells](http://bethecoder.com/applications/tutorials/excel/jexcel-api/how-to-wrap-text-in-excel-cells.html)

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import jxl.Workbook;
import jxl.format.Alignment;
import jxl.read.biff.BiffException;
import jxl.write.Label;
import jxl.write.WritableCellFormat;
import jxl.write.WritableSheet;
import jxl.write.WritableWorkbook;
import jxl.write.WriteException;

public class CellWrapTest {

  /**
   * @param args
   * @throws IOException 
   * @throws IOException 
   * @throws WriteException 
   * @throws BiffException 
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, WriteException {
    //Creates a writable workbook with the given file name
    WritableWorkbook workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File("C:/JXL/CellWrap.xls"));

    //Create sheet and add a label
    WritableSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("My Sheet", 0);

      WritableCellFormat cellFormat = new WritableCellFormat();
      cellFormat.setAlignment(Alignment.RIGHT);
      cellFormat.setWrap(true);

    sheet.addCell(new Label(1, 1, "A simple test message", cellFormat));    
    sheet.addCell(new Label(1, 2, "JXL Tutorials from BE THE CODER", cellFormat));

    //Writes out the data held in this workbook in Excel format
    workbook.write(); 

    //Close and free allocated memory 
    workbook.close(); 
  }

}
```

If anyone want to use another API, it's ok. But I want working solution. Help.

Comment: do you want to make your sheet editable?

Comment: not necessarily. make it as you want. But I want as mentioned in question..

Comment: my means , do you want to make excel in which cell is editable or want to include some text at a time of creating excel from system?